# What is the difference between UpSampling2D and Conv2DTranspose functions in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, convolution, deconvolution

Here in this code `UpSampling2D` and `Conv2DTranspose` seem to be used interchangeably. I want to know why this is happening.

```
# u-net model with up-convolution or up-sampling and weighted binary-crossentropy as loss func

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, concatenate, Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras import backend as K

def unet_model(n_classes=5, im_sz=160, n_channels=8, n_filters_start=32, growth_factor=2, upconv=True,
               class_weights=[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3]):
    droprate=0.25
    n_filters = n_filters_start
    inputs = Input((im_sz, im_sz, n_channels))
    #inputs = BatchNormalization()(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    #pool1 = Dropout(droprate)(pool1)

    n_filters *= growth_factor
    pool1 = BatchNormalization()(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    pool2 = Dropout(droprate)(pool2)

    n_filters *= growth_factor
    pool2 = BatchNormalization()(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    pool3 = Dropout(droprate)(pool3)

    n_filters *= growth_factor
    pool3 = BatchNormalization()(pool3)
    conv4_0 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
    conv4_0 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4_0)
    pool4_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4_0)
    pool4_1 = Dropout(droprate)(pool4_1)

    n_filters *= growth_factor
    pool4_1 = BatchNormalization()(pool4_1)
    conv4_1 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4_1)
    conv4_1 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4_1)
    pool4_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4_1)
    pool4_2 = Dropout(droprate)(pool4_2)

    n_filters *= growth_factor
    conv5 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4_2)
    conv5 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

    n_filters //= growth_factor
    if upconv:
        up6_1 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv5), conv4_1])
    else:
        up6_1 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4_1])
    up6_1 = BatchNormalization()(up6_1)
    conv6_1 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6_1)
    conv6_1 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6_1)
    conv6_1 = Dropout(droprate)(conv6_1)

    n_filters //= growth_factor
    if upconv:
        up6_2 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv6_1), conv4_0])
    else:
        up6_2 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6_1), conv4_0])
    up6_2 = BatchNormalization()(up6_2)
    conv6_2 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6_2)
    conv6_2 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6_2)
    conv6_2 = Dropout(droprate)(conv6_2)

    n_filters //= growth_factor
    if upconv:
        up7 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv6_2), conv3])
    else:
        up7 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6_2), conv3])
    up7 = BatchNormalization()(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)
    conv7 = Dropout(droprate)(conv7)

    n_filters //= growth_factor
    if upconv:
        up8 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv7), conv2])
    else:
        up8 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7), conv2])
    up8 = BatchNormalization()(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)
    conv8 = Dropout(droprate)(conv8)

    n_filters //= growth_factor
    if upconv:
        up9 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv8), conv1])
    else:
        up9 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8), conv1])
    conv9 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(n_classes, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv10)

    def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
        class_loglosses = K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=[0, 1, 2])
        return K.sum(class_loglosses * K.constant(class_weights))

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=weighted_binary_crossentropy)
    return model
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

UpSampling2D is just a simple scaling up of the image by using nearest neighbour or bilinear upsampling, so nothing smart. Advantage is it's cheap.

Conv2DTranspose is a convolution operation whose kernel is learnt (just like normal conv2d operation) while training your model. Using Conv2DTranspose will also upsample its input but the key difference is the model should learn what is the best upsampling for the job.

EDIT: Link to nice visualization of transposed convolution: https://towardsdatascience.com/types-of-convolutions-in-deep-learning-717013397f4d

Comment: So Conv2DTranspose is UpSampling2D and Conv2D, isn't it? Thanks.

Comment: To my understanding, in some cases Conv2DTranspose can be equal to UpSampling2D+Conv2d but that is not the general case no.

Comment: What would you recommend? Apply only UpSampling2d or combine it with a conv2d? I am trying to understand what would be a good approach for this kind of case or if I will get fewer parameters if I only use UpSampling2d. Thanks!

Comment: Depends what you want to do. Upsampling2D is just going to do a simple scaling using either nearest neighbour or bilinear methods. If you want to do something different than that you will need to use Conv2DTranspose or do Upsampling2D and follow with a Conv2D and hope your network learns something better this way.

UpSampling2D has no learned parameters its just nearest neighbour or bilinear scaling.